# how to update progess in PsRemotingJob?

Tags: powershell

When starting a job in powershell with start-job an object psremotingjob is returned.
A get-member on a PsRemotingJob gives us :

```
 TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSRemotingJob

Name          MemberType     Definition                                       
----          ----------     ----------                                       
[...]
Progress      Property       System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`...
StatusMessage Property       System.String StatusMessage {get;}               
Verbose       Property       System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`...
Warning       Property       System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`...
State         ScriptProperty System.Object State {get=$this.JobStateInfo.St...
```

So I wondered if I can update the property "Progress" from the job itself ?
I built the progressRecord collection, but I do not know how to get the job's properties from inside.

```
$VMlist  = @("VM1","VM2")

foreach($VM in $VMlist)
{
    $j = start-job -name $VM -argumentlist @($path,$VM)  -ScriptBlock {
        $psdatacollectionExample = New-Object 'System.Management.Automation.PSDataCollection`1[System.Management.Automation.ProgressRecord]'
        $progressRecord = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ProgressRecord(1,"Task1","Installing")
        for($i=0;$i -lt 5; $i++)
        {
            $progressRecord.PercentComplete = $i * 20
            $psdatacollectionExample.Add($progressRecord)   
            #something like super.Progess = $psdatacollectionExample

        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call write-progress from inside the server-side job script, like it was a local script. Then, on the client side, you use receive-job to retrieve the progress records like any other records (warning, error etc.) If you write them to the local consoles output stream, it will render the progress bar for you.

So:

```
for($i=0;$i -lt 5; $i++)
{
    $progressRecord.PercentComplete = $i * 20
    write-progress $progressRecord
}
```

As simple as that!

**Update:**

Here's a simple example demonstrating progress reporting from a remote job. `Start-Job` jobs use the remoting protocol, so they are effectively "remote" to localhost - the same code works with `Invoke-Command`.

```
PS> $job = start-job { 0..10 | % {
        write-progress -Id 1 -Activity "remote job" -Status "working..." `
          -PercentComplete ($_ * 10); sleep -seconds 2 } }
PS> receive-job $job -Wait
```

The above script will display the progress bar in 10% increments until the job completes.

Comment: I Did try to receive the job. But It throws me an error : Property "status" cannot be found. So I added $progressRecord.Status = "Running" am I missing something ?

Comment: In fact, the receive-job was waiting for a status property. By the way, i did not get the progress bar. write-progress doesnot seem to get the parameter correctly

Comment: You need to reduce your code to the simplest it can be to demonstrate progress reporting from a remote job. You have too much fluff in it right now to know what's causing what.

Comment: After several tries, i also found out that the example you gave was the solution. The object progressrecord does not seem to work with write-progress.  Thank you for your help.